# Number of pages a program occupies

Tags: c++, c, virtual-memory, data-caching

I found this problem in an OS past paper and I need some help in figuring it out.
*You are given:*

- *a matrix A with 10 lines and 10 columns that are being stored contiguously by lines*
- *a system in which we have 3 available page frames; in this system, you can fit 10 integers in a page*
- *2 programs, `P1` and `P2`, that fit, on their own and together, in one page; the programs are:*

```
    P1:
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
       for(j=0; j<10; j++)
           A[i][j]=0;

    P2:
    for(j=0; j<10; j++)
       for(i=0; i<10; i++)
           A[i][j]=0;
```

The question is: *How many pages does each program occupy and which one is more efficient given that we are using the LRU algorithm?*

I know how the LRU algorithm works and my guess would be that `P1` is more efficient because the matrix is stored contiguously by lines. But I don't understand where LRU fits in this logic (please correct me if my reasoning is wrong). Concerning the number of pages that each program occupies, we've never covered that in class. Can someone help me?

If it helps, the answer options are:

- `P1` and `P2` occupy 11 pages each and `P1` is more efficient
- `P1` and `P2` occupy 11 pages each and `P2` is more efficient
- `P1` and `P2` occupy 100 pages each and `P2` is more efficient
- `P1` and `P2` occupy 10 pages each and `P1` is more efficient
- `P1` and `P2` occupy 10 pages each and `P2` is more efficient

Also, I have a feeling this question is "inspired" by this problem in Operating System Concepts Essentials (maybe it could provide some context):

[image]

Comment: "contiguously by lines" means that the "lines" must correspond to the right-most dimension of a 2D array in C, because that one is the one with the contiguous guarantee by the language. In your case the `j` index. The original question is poorly explained, there's no obvious connection between this C code and these artificial "pages" of... what? Data? Code? "fit 10 integers in a page" suggests data, but neither example allocates any data.

Comment: Sorry for the poorly written question, I have the same amount of information you have. The question was poorly written in the first place, I just translated it from my native language. I'm obviously confused, but I'm trying to figure out some sort of solution, as I could get something similar in my exam.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant as well, the original question is too vague to make sense of.

Comment: @Lundin I just added the answer options and a possible source of "inspiration" for this problem, maybe it can provide some context.

Comment: Well, the screenshot question makes a whole lot more sense. This is apparently about data cache. Except `int A[][]` isn't valid C and `new` is C++. And it doesn't mention if those page sizes are 200 bytes or 200 integers, which is kind of essential knowledge that one must have to answer.